# Promises, argument in .then() is undefined, how to pass?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I am following [a guide](https://github.com/pusher/react-slack-clone/blob/8c7d5eb006127aa7ffdcaf3a12f12a63f201c6eb/src/chatkit.js) to run some parent functions inside a Promise. That is a React example, I am using Vue.js.

My problem is that even though I build the Promise exactly like the example I still run into a `actions undefined` issue.

Namely the argument `actions` is not defined inside the `then` method.

I understand that `.then()` creates a new object and I should explicitly pass arguments to that object. This creates 2 questions:

1. How come the argument `actions` is defined inside `.then()` in the example.
   Is it because of Vue and React differences?
2. Since the `connect()` resolves to `user` object implicitly, how do I bind or add an extra variable (in my case the `actions` argument) to the resolve method.

Here is my singleton code:

```
var chatKitConnectionSingleton = (function () {
  var instance;

  function init({ state, actions }, uid) {

    new ChatManager({
      instanceLocator: "##:###:###-###-###-###",
      userId: uid,
      tokenProvider: new TokenProvider({url: '...' })
    })
      .connect({
      onAddedToRoom: room => {
        actions.selectRoomAsCurrent(room)
      },
      onRemovedFromRoom: room => {
        actions.removeRoomLocally(room.id)
      },
      onRoomDeleted: room => {
        actions.removeRoomLocally(room.id)
      }
    })
      .then(user => {
      actions.setCurrentUser(user)
      Promise.all(
        user.rooms.map(room =>
                       user.subscribeToRoom({
          roomId: room.id,
          hooks: {
            onNewMessage: message => {
              actions.newMessageArrived(message)
            }
          },
          messageLimit: 10
        })
                      )
      ).then(rooms => {
        actions.setRoomsFromChatkit(rooms)

      }).catch(err =>{
        actions.setRoomsFromChatkit([])
      })
    })
      .catch(error => console.log('CHATKIT | Error on connection', error))
  };

  return {

    getInstance: function ({ state, actions },uid) {
      if ( !instance ) {
        instance = init({ state, actions },uid);
      }
      return instance;
    }
  };
})();
```

***EDIT***

I just figured out that the `actions` argument is undefined in the connect hooks as well :|

I guess the real question is, how to pass Vue component `methods` to a singleton.

Currently, I am doing this, but it resolves to `actions` undefined.

```
  let chatManagerConnectPromise = chatConnection(this, uid)
```

Meaning `this` will not resolve to `{state, actions}` like in React. Does anyone know how to do this in Vue?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. `actions` is undefined even before the `return Promise.all(` as well as inside the Promise, even with your suggested edit.

Comment: can you change this function init({ state, actions }, uid) {  -> to ({state, actions}, uid) => {}

Answer (score 0):

actions is outside of the function scope. you need to bind manually or use ES6 arrow functions to avoid undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is me overthinking the problem.

In Vue, when passing `this` to an external function, Vue doesn't treat it as `{state, actions}` like React.

The argument (which in my case is `this`) should be used in the same way as it is used inside the component itself. Calling methods by `this.myMethod()`

I changed the argument from `{state, actions}` -> `actions` at it all worked.

Thanks for the pointers!